# Hide "onclick" line (display:none) when a certain screen size is reached / responsiv

Tags: php, css, onclick, responsive

In my code, a modal window opens when you click on it. In the responsive view this view is not user friendly so I want to hide the whole "onclick" line. I already tried with css tags (display-none) in combination with media query, but that doesn't work.

```
<a
                class="<?php echo ($display == 'thumbs' ? 'ImageWrapperLarge' : 'ImageWrapper') ?>"
                onClick="return <?php echo ($pageid_view_modal?"Modal":"CentralSpace") ?>Load(this,true);"
                href="<?php echo $baseurl_short . ("page.php?id=" . $id) ?>"
                title="<?php echo str_replace(array("\"","'"),"",specialchars(i18n_get_translated(strip_tags(strip_tags_and_attributes($result[$n]["field".$title_field])))))?>"
            >
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide onClick line, you should be creating another link instead.

```css
.mobile-link {
  display: none;
}


/* Yes, Samsung S21 is 515px wide */

@media screen and (max-width: 515px) {
  .mobile-link {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .desktop-link {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="desktop-link" onClick="alert('Do something');" href=" # " title="Desktop Link ">Desktop Link</a>
<a class="mobile-link" href=" # " title="Desktop Link ">Mobile Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to check the width of `window` and disable your onClick accordingly.

I haven't tested it, but you could probably just change your onClick to

```
<!-- using 400px generically !-->
<a onClick="window.innerWidth > 400 ? return <?php echo ($pageid_view_modal?"Modal":"CentralSpace") ?>Load(this,true); : null">
</a>
```